# Onclick Export Query Results from Access to Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to do an export of data from my access db to an excel spreadsheet. Everything was smooth until I tried to code an onclick event for a form. Here is the code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, "ReportQuery", "C:\helloworld.xlsx", True
```

The error I am getting is 'Runtime Error 3051' The Microsoft Access Database engine cannot open or write to the file ... It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view and write its data.

I find it hard to believe that the engine doesn't have permission. Is there a setting or something I am missing here?

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to create a file in C:\ ? If you open Notepad, type "Hello" and then try to save it as `C:\hello.txt` are you successful?

Comment: Access runs with the privileges of the user/process which starts it.  It doesn't run as a special system account.

Comment: Ahh. I see. Yes. That was the problem. I used C:\ as a test location before attempting a network drive path. My mistake! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you do not have sufficient permissions to write to the root directory of drive `C:`. When testing, always choose a "safe" location (like your Documents folder) for creating or updating files.

BTW, you'll probably have better success if you use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` instead of `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` when creating `.xlsx` files.